# LM317 vs AMS1117 as constant current limiter for LED SMD boards

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-limiting, constant-current

I need to design a board like this:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Each LED is an [SMD 5730](https://www.banggood.com/200pcs-0_5W-SMD-5730-LED-Lamp-Chip-Bead-for-Strip-light-p-1088369.html) type with a maximum current of 150 mA in three line and the input voltage is 3.2 × 7 ≈ 23 V.

[image]

I have seen this circuit:

[image]

But I found the AMS1117 which is more stable on stress by this [datasheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) part:

> Unlike  older  regulators,  the  AMS1117  family  does  not  need  any protection  diodes  between  the  adjustment  pin  and  the  output and from  the  output  to  the  input  to  prevent  over-stressing  the  die. Internal  resistors  are  limiting  the  internal  current  paths  on  the AMS1117  adjustment  pin,  therefore  even  with  capacitors  on  the adjustment  pin  no  protection  diode  is  needed to  ensure  device safety under short-circuit conditions. Diodes  between  the  input  and  output  are  not  usually  needed.
> Microsecond surge currents of 50A to 100A can be handled by the internal diode between the input and output pins of the device. In normal  operations  it  is  difficult  to  get  those  values  of  surge currents  even  with  the  use  of  large  output  capacitances.
> If  high value  output  capacitors  are  used,  such  as  1000μF  to  5000μF  and the  input  pin  is  instantaneously  shorted  to  ground, damage  can occur.  A  diode  from  output  to  input  is  recommended,  when  a crowbar circuit at the input of the AMS1117 is used (Figure 1).

[image]

It could give me almost 1 A at almost a 1.3 V drop and a max. Vin of 15 V, so by this connection type:

[image]

I would like to know if the LM317 is better than the AMS1117 by some factors. I care about its price; the AMS1117 price is almost 1/3 of the LM317's price, and maximum voltage offers (which I don't think I need here because the open loop doesn't pass any voltage on an adjustable voltage IC).

I have also seen this question:

[LM317 Constant Current vs Transistor Current Limiter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439789/lm317-constant-current-vs-transistor-current-limiter?rq=1)

I think the LM317 or AMS1117 are better for this usage, am I right?

Comment: for this usage, it really should make little difference. Both are wrong here. Don't just copy circuits from somewhere else without understanding what they're doing.

Answer (score 7):

If your voltage drop is 15V, and your current is 450 mA, then your linear regulator, no matter whether it's just a transistor, a LM317 or an AMS1117, will have to dissipate 7W.

That's an insane amount of power you waste and convert to heat. They will all overheat.

So, you're wrong, and all your solutions are inadequate; they are wrong "by the same amount".

In fact, you're also misinterpreting what "current limit" is here. But that's been asked multiple times on here...

You need a switch-mode power supply here. And you don't want a constant-voltage supply, but a constant-current supply, so design accordingly. Actually, I'd argue you'd really want *three* constant current supplies, one for each string, to avoid thermal runaway if any of your LEDs has a lower forward voltage than the others.

Comment: I agree; I would also add 'open LED' sensing for the supplies.

Comment: I wonder if Class-A audiophiles would agree that 7 W is an insane amount of power to waste as heat…

Comment: @pipe well, assuming that someone who builds Class-A amplifiers can read an LM317 datasheet...

Answer (score -1):

AMS1117 is better . because the voltage drop of it is only 1.25v . it is an LDO it needs only 1.1-1.3v more than the output to work . the 317 is ldo also but needs more than 2v.

and with this drop and 450mA it will dissipate only about 600mW .

those people saying 7w is maybe confusing with the 15v which is the maximum voltage that it support between (vin - vout) , and in the case of using to reg current like that the vin-vout will be always 1.25v .

Comment: The voltage applied to this circuit is never specified by the OP. It could be 2V more than what the LED strip requires, or it could be 15V. You are assuming a minimum regulation condition, but the maximum input voltage is the worst case. The LM317 is not a low-dropout (LDO) regulator.

Comment: Downvoting because the last sentence is wrong (and correct answers have already been provided almost three years ago).

Answer (score -1):

Use constant current IC like LT3092. It can configure for 200mA of current. If this IC is not compatible then search for any other constant current IC. Voltage regulators like AMS1117 are not designed for constant current operation for LEDs.

Comment: The LM317 and AMS1117 and other adjustable linear voltage regulators are well suited for constant current LED drivers as long as voltage drop and power dissipation are within appropriate limits. Also, the LT3092 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3092.pdf costs about $6 and can dissipate only a couple watts. Please read the OP's question and the answers that have already been provided before posting a non-helpful answer. Sorry to seem harsh - I know you are a new contributor - but criticism is to be expected.